# PostgreSQL: Select from table only if table exists

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, postgresql-12

I am an SQL noob, and I have been trying to select data only if a table exists, and nothing if it doesn't. I've looked at various solutions, and this is the best I've been able to come up with:

```
DO $$                  
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
              FROM   information_schema.tables 
              WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
              AND    table_name = "Test_Table"
            )
        THEN
            SELECT
              test_col
            FROM "Test_Table"
            ORDER BY time ASC
        END IF ;
    END
$$ ;
```

but this gives:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 14:         END IF ;
```

Note that the table name may contain uppercase characters, so I believe the double quotes are necessary.

Any ideas? Maybe trying to catch an exception would be a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying to do.  Are you aware that `select into` creates a *table* and not a value for a column?

Answer (score 1):

```
DO $$                  
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
              FROM   information_schema.tables 
              WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
              AND    table_name = 'Test_Table' -- use single quotes, it's value
            )
        THEN
            SELECT
              test_col
            FROM "Test_Table" -- advice: never use Upper case and you don't need double quotes
            ORDER BY time ASC; -- use a ; at the end of the query
        END IF ;
    END
$$ ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The `;` does fix the syntax error, and the query works as desired if the table does not exist. However, if the table does exist, I get:
`ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 10 at SQL statement`
instead of seeing the results returned like I am used to. Any ideas on how to actually get those rows?

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 issues in your block, both involving the select statement:

1. The select statement does not have the required terminating
   semi-colon (;)
2. Since the select is in a DO block it requires the INTO clause for
   columns selected.

Try:

```
DO $$  
    declare 
       l_test_col "Test_Table".test_col%type = 'Nothing selected: table does not exist.'                
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
              FROM   information_schema.tables 
              WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
              AND    table_name = "Test_Table"
            )
        THEN
            SELECT
              test_col
             into l_test_col
            FROM "Test_Table"
            ORDER BY time ASC
        END IF ;
        
        rise notice 'Result: %',l_test_col;  
    END
$$ ;
```

The above is restricted to "Test_Table" containing exactly 1 row if it does exist.

Comment: This won't work when the table doesn't exist: l_test_col depends on the existence of this table.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: OOPS. True, and so does the select itself. Guess that comes from *never* creating a table in a procedure. You just forget little things like that!